# Count number of objects in a region

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a tibble with coordinates of objects on image for many images. I want to calculate the number of images that resides in the box of specified size around the each object (something like number of neighbors). So far I came up with the `for` loop which subset the tibble and count number of rows.

```
raw.data <- structure(list(ImageNumber = c(67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 
67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 
67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 
67), ObjectNumber = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 16, 34, 35, 
42, 44, 46, 54, 58, 67, 77, 82, 90, 94, 107, 153, 158, 169, 201, 
223, 254, 294, 315, 386, 493, 508, 553, 599, 606, 612, 625, 676, 
678, 697), Location_Center_X.nuc = c(46.3557910673732, 189.630407911001, 
238.322766570605, 253.236234458259, 134.482566248257, 45.7193336698637, 
136.949320148331, 292.452631578947, 238.591869918699, 147.364275668073, 
93.859943977591, 169.394435351882, 253.794247787611, 97.1797752808989, 
258.430194805195, 233.346428571429, 202.378378378378, 297.966403162055, 
229.343333333333, 298.730679156909, 243.604806408545, 256.607266435986, 
279.823886639676, 288.966666666667, 278.035714285714, 264.86592178771, 
161.519230769231, 280.364672364672, 299.832929782082, 271.572481572482, 
7.72075471698113, 5.81395348837209, 284.742857142857, 291.826747720365, 
5.4331983805668, 295.924778761062, 198.463709677419, 282.083094555874, 
248.316239316239, 281.019867549669, 19.6458333333333), Location_Center_Y.nuc = c(237.48145344436, 
56.1885043263288, 175.412103746398, 144.548845470693, 199.902370990237, 
122.95406360424, 23.9406674907293, 266.46015037594, 116.671544715447, 
122.617440225035, 20.5756302521008, 152.31914893617, 93.3495575221239, 
167.223314606742, 195.261363636364, 26.0714285714286, 123.351351351351, 
227.009881422925, 85.19, 41.9789227166276, 290.567423230975, 
34.9671280276817, 164.975708502024, 91.5090909090909, 39.7205882352941, 
222.66852886406, 238.157692307692, 73.1880341880342, 191.019370460048, 
128.415233415233, 107.4, 37.5488372093023, 210.244155844156, 
131.577507598784, 150.072874493927, 152.650442477876, 3.77016129032258, 
110.702005730659, 2.28205128205128, 3.02649006622517, 2.59027777777778
)), row.names = c(NA, -41L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

radius = 80
raw.data$Density.80 = NA;

for (i in 1:nrow(raw.data)){
  x = raw.data$Location_Center_X.nuc[i]
  y = raw.data$Location_Center_Y.nuc[i]
  imN = raw.data$ImageNumber[i]
  sub_samp = raw.data[which(raw.data$Location_Center_X.nuc >= x-radius &
                              raw.data$Location_Center_X.nuc <= x+radius &
                              raw.data$Location_Center_Y.nuc >= y-radius &
                              raw.data$Location_Center_Y.nuc <= y+radius &
                              raw.data$ImageNumber == imN),]
  raw.data$Density.80[i] = nrow(sub_samp) - 1
}
```

The problem is that with large datasets (tens to hundreds of thousand objects in hundreds to thousand images) this process take hours. Hence optimization of box size will take forever.

I want to write a function that might speedup that process. This is my try that returns single number per image, not a number for each object. And I also struggle with the way how to apply such function with `purrr::map_*`

```
count_neighbors <- function(.data, radius, ...){
  .data %>%
    group_by(ImageNumber) %>%
    filter(between(Location_Center_X.nuc, Location_Center_X.nuc - radius, Location_Center_X.nuc + radius) &
             between(Location_Center_Y.nuc, Location_Center_Y.nuc - radius, Location_Center_Y.nuc + radius)) %>%
    tally()
    
}

count_neighbors(raw.data, radius = 80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function which calculates number of objects in the region for one object.

```
count_values <- function(x, y, xVal, yVal, radius) {
  sum(xVal >= x-radius & xVal <= x+radius &
    yVal >= y-radius & yVal <= y+radius) - 1
}
```

You can use this function for each object in the image.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

raw.data %>%
  group_by(ImageNumber) %>%
  mutate(result = map2_dbl(Location_Center_X.nuc, Location_Center_Y.nuc, 
                       ~count_values(.x, .y, Location_Center_X.nuc, 
                                     Location_Center_Y.nuc, 80))) -> raw.data

raw.data
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `1:nrow(df)` as the main argument to purrr's map.

```
get_image_counts <- function(df, distance){
  
purrr::map(1:nrow(df), function(idx){
  
  x <- df[idx,] %>% pull(Location_Center_X.nuc)
  y <- df[idx,] %>% pull(Location_Center_Y.nuc)
  
  df %>% filter(Location_Center_X.nuc > x - distance & Location_Center_X.nuc < x + distance &
                      Location_Center_Y.nuc > y - distance & Location_Center_Y.nuc < y + distance) %>% 
    nrow
  
}) %>% unlist

}

raw.data %>% tibble::add_column(neighbs = get_image_counts(raw.data, radius))
```

One nice thing about this solution is that it works nicely with multiple images.

```
raw.data %>% group_split(ImageNumber) %>% purrr::map(function(df){
  
  df %>% tibble::add_column(neighbs = get_image_counts(df, radius))
  
})
```

This will get you a list of tibbles with a new column, neighbs, that gives counts of neighboring objects within images, which I think is what you're looking for. Can't say whether this solves your problem without seeing the full data. If it's too slow, you may want to use the furrr package, which provides parallelized map functions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however the obtained results is different from what I got with my for loop. Not sure why it so, but anyway the other answer solved my problem.